# Access intranet website from outside

Tags: ssh, proxy, http, ssh-tunnel

In the framework I'm working with I can monitor certain things on a website. This website can only be reached from within the network. If I'm at work I can simply use my favorite browser and navigate to this website. If I'm at home, that won't work. What I can do, is login onto an interactive machine with ssh, start firefox there and navigate to the website. That works, but needless to say it is super slow, due to X11 forwarding for graphics being so inefficient.

Can I tell my browser to somehow use this server, that I usually ssh into as a proxy or can I do some other ssh magic to tunnel my way from home to this website?

Comment: Unless you have a VPN setup, that allows you to connect to the network the server is connected to, what you want is not possible.  This assumes even that would work.  You didn't really tell us anything about how the server is configured, only that, you can't access it from home.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for not being clear. Point is, I don't understand the setup myself. For example I do not know how the server is configured (I assume you mean the webserver). I only know there is a website that I cannot access as soon as I leave from work. I guess it has to be possible to access it with a tunnel somehow, since I've seen people doing it before. It's possible (even likely) that I'm just not explaining myself well enough.

Answer (score 2):

SSH supports forwarding TCP connections, and most decent SSH clients can use this both to forward individual host:ports (creating listeners on localhost) and to act as a SOCKS5 proxy that you can configure in a browser (works best in Firefox). The latter is usually named "dynamic forwarding".

With both OpenSSH and PuTTY's `plink` you can get a proxy listening at `localhost:1080` like this:

```
ssh -D 1080 foo.example.com
```

The equivalent graphical PuTTY option is under *Connection → SSH → [Tunnels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGzPP.png)*; enter e.g. 1080 as "Source port" and click "Add" before starting the connection.

(Make sure to configure the browser to use this as a [SOCKS proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t54Uv.png), not HTTP proxy.)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. I'm trying to set this up, but I do not know how. I think the `ssh` command is to be typed on the interactive machine that I connect to and wchi *can* access the website? I tried this but it doesn't work, I get `Could not resolve hostname`.

Comment: No, you type it on the machine you're connecting _from_. You're just adding the `-D` option to your regular SSH connection.

Comment: Same error as before. The only thing I change w.r.t. my absolutely first try is adding `-D 1080` as a flag to the ssh command. Am I missing something else? Might it be of importance that I

Comment: How do you connect to this server usually?

Comment: I assume you are talking to the server I `ssh` to? I use kerberos to authenticate.

Comment: The authentication method shouldn't matter at all, and the `-D` option shouldn't change anything hostname-related at all...

Comment: I'll give it another try tomorrow. Right now I can't find a way to make hist